# Factorial modulo some number

Tags: algorithm, math

In order to calculate factorial for each and every number until some large number modulo some number and store in an array that is  1 to n(10000000).There is a naive process I have been trying, iterating for each and every number and calculating it and taking modulo and using the previous calculated result.Is there any good algorithm for performing this in order to get fastest execution time? Code which I have tried is as follows:

```
int a[10000000]={};
int m;//some large number
a[0] = a[1] = 0;
for(int i = 2; i < 10000000; i++)
{
  a[i] = a[i] % m;
}
```

Comment: Specify the language, show your code.

Comment: Yes, that exactly @genisage wrote just now.

Comment: If that's already what you're doing, I don't think there's a much better way to fill an array. If you give us more information about the context we might be able to help you figure out exactly which parts are hurting performance and improve them.

Comment: It's a part of an ongoing contest on Codechef.

Comment: _Ongoing_... You should have mentioned that in your question right from the start. _Sigh_

Comment: 1!=1 and 0!=1 (just cause).  Do you want some multiplication at some point?  And do you really need the factorial of everything?  Or just the factorial of a particula big number, modulo some other big number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the modulus m is less than or equal to the factorial argument n, then n! = 0 mod m
(because m will be a divisor of n!).